# redis start with /usr/bin/redis-server fine but stop on systemd start

Tags: redis, centos8

I have install redis on centos 8 and everything works fine but after I have reboot the server, redis top working, I have try to start by `systemctl start redis` but service start and stop unexpectedly
I have try `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf` and service start successfully but still got following error on starting bye systemctl

```
redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

can anybody help me about this?

-----edit-------
I have check `/var/logs/redis/redis.log` and found that se linux cause the problme
I have try `setenforce permissive` and now redis working fine.
but why this happend?
I didn`t change anything about SELinux and suddenly the error occurred